# Only enable whitespace mode in certain buffers

Tags: elisp, local-variables, whitespace-mode

I would like to have whitespace mode turned on for all buffer except for org-mode ones.  It is easy to do this when emacs starts up, but since I use a persistant copy of emacs with emacs daemon mode I can't just do it that way.

I tried:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-line-column 80)
(setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail))
(global-whitespace-mode t)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
          (visual-line-mode 1)
          (auto-fill-mode -1)
          (setq whitespace-style nil)))
```

but as soon as I visit an org-mode buffer all of my future buffers don't have whitespace mode any more.

I thought of adding a hook to turn whitespace mode on for other major-modes but that seems like a bad way to go since I don't want to enumerate all the other possible modes.

I know that there is whitespace-mode along with global-whitespace-mode, but I'm not sure how I can use that to help here either.

Is there some other way to accomplish this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: You could modify the `global-whitespace-mode` definition by adding `(unless (eq major-mode 'org-mode) . . .)`.  Or, you could enable it on a per major-mode basis instead of globally -- i.e., for each major-mode, use a hook and `(whitespace-mode 1)`.  Your idea may also work if you use `(setq-local whitespace-style nil)`, but technically the mode is still active with just the guts / umph taken out.

Comment: Unrelated: [You should not quote your `lambda`s](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html)

Comment: Good point about the quoted lambda.  Not sure how or why I ended up with it that way but I removed it from my .emacs  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(setq whitespace-global-modes '(not org-mode))
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `whitespace-global-modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: That works perfect.  Thanks.  I knew that there had to be something simple that I was missing.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably easier to turn off whitespace mode directly, using

```
 (whitespace-mode -1)
```

Also, `whitespace-style` is not a buffer-local variable, so it is modified for all other buffers as well. Try instead

```
(set (make-local-variable 'whitespace-style) nil)
```

Comment: I actually had initially turned whitespace-mode off directly rather than fussing with the whitespace-style var.  That was just the current iteration of my attempts.  I'm going to try what people suggested and then update this with what worked for me.

Comment: This actually works too, but as you commented yourself, directly turning whitespace mode off rather than dealing with the style is a better solution (which the answer above this does).